# Rest Assured: What is the best way to test a raw response body?

Tags: rest-assured

I have a get request which simply returns a simple string:

```
given()
.when()
.get("https://www.example.com")
```

This get returns a simple string, for example "123".

Is there a cooler way to verify it other than using for example:

```
Assert.assertEquals("123",
      given()
     .when()
     .get("https://www.example.com").asString());
```

Something like:

```
      given()
     .when()
     .get("https://www.example.com")
     .then()
     .statusCode(200);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use method `T body(Matcher<?> matcher, Matcher<?>... additionalMatchers);`

Example:

```
given()
.get("https://www.example.com")
.then()
.statusCode(200)
.body(is("text_in_body"));
```